# Cómo sustituir un div de una página web por otro que está en otra página web

Tags: html, div

Quería poder intercambiar un div (contiene: clase contenedor principal) que tengo en una página web (página 1) por otro div (contiene: clase contenedor principal) que se encuentra en otra página web (página 2), este intercambio se debe producir cuando se produzca pulse sobre un link.

```
pagina 1.html
<div class="contedor-principal">
    <div class="noticias">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
pagina 2.html
<div class="contedor-principal">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

En la página 1 (página 1.html) hay un enlace que apunta a la página 2.html. La cosa es que quiero que se cargue el contenido de la página 2.html en el lugar de la pagina 1.html

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. La idea del sitio es que realices preguntas específicas, mostrando el código relevante de lo que has intentado y dando una explicación razonable del problema, del comportamiento actual y del resultado esperado. Puedes leer [mcve] como una guía. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, parece un pedido al tendero o al panadero: *quiero un pan sin glúten, bajo en calorías*. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

1. En lugar de enlace que sea un botón ya que el enlace siempre te llevará a otra página.
2. La respuesta está en las etiquetas iFrame o embed que te permiten incrustar contenido en una página.
3. Creas un evento de tipo Click al botón y le pasas al atributo src del iframe o embed la ruta de tu página 2 esto debería de mostrar el contenido el contenido de tu página 2 incrustado en tu página 1.